# How does the server knows the message queue is destroyed

Tags: c, linux, message-queue

I have a written a small server client message queue program, where the server creates the message queue, writes into the queue and client gets the message queue id and reads the written data from the queue.

The problem is, client will destroy/remove the queue once the client is stopped/restarted. And the server will be attempting to write into the queue, but it fails. When the client starts again it creates a new message queue, now is there any possibilities that server can know the message queue is created and start writing into the queue. Or is there any another method to overcome this situation.

Note : Server cannot destroy the queue as the written data should be read by the client.

Thanks.

Comment: The client creates the queue where? Doesn't the server create the queue? The client should be aware of the server and vice versa, I don't see where the problem is.

Comment: Pick either the server or the client, and have that end solely responsible for queue creation and teardown. There may be some additional logic needed - e.g. server waits to tear down queue until it's been emptied, or client refuses to start if it can't locate the queue created by the server - but a cleaner design will lead to fewer headaches long term...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the client and server share the queue id. so you need to poll for the queueid using ipcs command.

Comment: thanks for the reply, Can you tell me how to poll the queueid?

Comment: I'd just write a script that does : "ipcs -q | grep 0x000004d2 | cut -c 1-10" . and popen that script in your C code and read the result back into your C program. This must be a seperate thread to compare against your message queue key.